# SQL Regex Search for Full name

Tags: regex

It's probably really simple.
So, I have this table, user
That has a field 'full_name'

Say I have entries like

```
"John Doe"
"Jane Doe"
"Colby Smith Jr"
"Apple Smith"
```

I need a regex search that will fit these conditions:

```
query = John => return 'John Doe'
query = Doe => return 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe'
query = Apple => return 'Apple Smith'
query = Smith => return 'Colby Smith Jr', 'Apply Smith'
query = Apple Smith => return 'Apple Smith'
query = Smith Jr => return 'Colby Smith Jr'
```

So basically, I need a regex function that will search 
query* (* being wildcard?)

OR
(first char after a space in my result strings)query

Does that make sense?
Basically, I'm trying to mimic the functionality in instagram's search.  Check that out if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex *per se*.  Translating your requirements:

```
... WHERE (full_name LIKE 'Doe%'    -- query + "wildcard" (that is, starts with query)
           OR                       -- or
           full_name LIKE '% Doe%)  -- space + query anywhere
```

If you're using parameterized queries — and you should be — construction of the LIKE pattern operand becomes a little more complex:  `... LIKE (? || '%') OR ... LIKE ('% ' || ? || '%')`.

Note that your database might spell string concatenation a bit differently.  (MySQL uses a function CONCAT() rather than ANSI double pipes, for instance.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL LIKE command, with the '%' operator.
Something like:-

```
    SELECT * FROM Names WHERE name LIKE "%Doe%";
```

Comment: This won't work because something like "jdoe martin" would be valid, and it shouldn't be.

Comment: True, pilcrow's answer is perfect in that respect. LIKE and % - SQL wildcard searching - gets you most of the way there though.